# How to clean up angular ui controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to angular.  I've included angular-ui so I can have bootstrap modals to add data.   Seems like i'd have to put all these functions EVERY controller that I wanted to have a modal in...seems kinda dumb to do it like that though.  Is there a way to make this thing more reusable?

```
lassoControllers.controller('PostsController', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$http', 'Post', '$modal',
function($scope, $timeout, $http, Post, $modal) {
    $scope.posts = Post.query();

    $scope.askDelete = function(item) {
        var message = "Are you sure ?";

        var modalHtml = '<div class="modal-body">' + message + '</div>';
        modalHtml += '<div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()">OK</button><button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button></div>';

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            template: modalHtml,
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function() {
            reallyDelete(item);
        });
    };

    var reallyDelete = function(item) {
        $scope.items = window._.remove($scope.items, function(elem) {
            return elem != item;
        });


    };

}]);
```

Comment: Put them in a service.

Comment: could also move the html into a template file

Answer (score 0):

I'm relatively new to Angular as well, but I've been using it fairly heavily for a few months, including some work with modals. To my knowledge, your code is pretty spot on. Unless the you find the actual logic you're implementing in to the modal to be redundant it's probably as modular as you'll get it.

You could clean it up a bit by moving the modal's HTML to a template file and then use `templateUrl:` to pull it in.

On a side note, [here](http://toddmotto.com/opinionated-angular-js-styleguide-for-teams/) is a pretty great Angular style guide to help get you on the right track with the framework overall. It explains the how/why reasoning behind various patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You are fundamentally correct in that in order to use Angular.js dependency injection, you have to inject a lot of services into the controller. This is unavoidable in a framework that uses constructor dependency injection. However, in your example you can factor out several of the services you are injecting. Some of them will still have an alternate that you will have to inject, but the alternate can factor out repeated code. While you are still injecting a lot of services, you will reduce the amount of boilerplate code you have to write.

## Services

#### $scope

If you use `controllerAs` syntax, you can simply put your properties on the controller and reference the controller within you templates. Todd Motto has a pretty good [explanation](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) of how it works. John Papa [recommends](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controllers) using this feature in his style guide.

#### $http

As a general rule, you shouldn't use $http directly in your controller. Instead, create a service to abstract the call to `$http`. It looks like the `Post` service may already be doing this. John Papa's style guide has a great [explanation](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#data-services) of the benefits of using a data service.

#### $modal

This can be also be abstracted to different services (e.g. a `ConfirmModalService`). This can be helpful to factor out code. For example if you are using `$timeout` for some confirmation modal purpose, you can just use it in your confirmation modal service and not in the template. As for the `modalHtml`, you can keep the html for the modal in that service as a property or save it in a html file and use `templateUrl` when instantiating the modal.

### Other style notes

If you want to simplify your controller more, you move some of the service (even the data service and modal abstractions I referenced above) into a separate service to abstract user interactions. There is really a lot of flexibility in how you organize your code.

I noticed that you were also using the global `window` object. This can be hard to mock when doing testing so the [suggested style](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y180) is to inject the angular `$window` service (I know another service). Testability is one of the core features of Angular.js and providing values to be injected into the constructor of controllers and services is one aspect of testing.

## Pseudo Implementation:

```
lassoControllers.controller('PostsController', ['$timeout', 'Post', 'ConfirmModalService',
function($timeout, Post, ConfirmModalService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.posts = Post.query();

    vm.askDelete = function(item) {
        var message = "Are you sure ?";
        var modalResult = ConfirmModalService.open(message).then(function() {
            vm.reallyDelete(item);
        });
    };

    vm.reallyDelete = function(item) {
        // Assuming this is an array
        vm.items = vm.items.filter(function(elem) {
            return elem != item;
        });
    };

}]);
```